# Statistical data of npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

*For whatever reason this question was [flagged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/stats-on-npm-packages?noredirect=1#comment476603_237551) as an off-topic on programmers.stackexchange.com.
I still believe it's a legitimate question, so even risking to be kicked again I'm still gonna try to ask it here.*

**Anyone ever tried gathering any stats on npm packages?**

**Is it possible for example to read npm low level api (if it even exists) and say get the information about how many packages have underscore.js as their dependency, or how many packages compiled from closurescript, typescript or coffeescript.**

I can't believe nobody ever tried to gather and analyze information about all existing npm packages or build dependency graphs and whatnots.

Upd: So most of the packages are hosted on github, and github contains information of the most prolific language in the given git repo. So I guess it is possible to query npm and retrieve detailed information about every single package. And maybe someone already tried doing that?

Comment: If you go to the npm homepage: https://www.npmjs.org/ they clearly have all of this data, as they display it on their homepage. Weather or not they make it publicly available is another question.

Comment: Is your question on how to do this with Node.js?

Comment: Yeah, I see you can get this: https://www.npmjs.org/browse/depended, but It doesn't answer the second part of the question

Comment: @Brad Maybe. Is it possible to fetch information from npm, using node?

Comment: Substack did some dependency graphing in 2011. At that time, npm had less than 1000 packages: http://substack.net/npm_graph

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I also don't know of any ready analysis, but,

`npm` uses couchdb, which is open for replication. See [this blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/75707294465/new-npm-registry-architecture) for a lot of info.
The couchdb contains tar balls that you can further process.